# Key is not present in table, but it is | Postgresql, timescaledb

Tags: sql, postgresql, timescaledb

I have next db.

```
CREATE TABLE DataLines(
    id        BIGSERIAL NOT NULL,
    TimeStamp TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    
    PRIMARY KEY (id, timestamp)
);

CREATE TABLE SpnValues(
    id         BIGSERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY                              ,
    valueInt   BIGINT    NOT NULL                                          ,
    dataLineId BIGSERIAL                                                   ,
    timestamp  TIMESTAMP NOT NULL                                          ,
    
    FOREIGN KEY (datalineid, timestamp) REFERENCES DataLines(id, timestamp)
);
```

When I try to insert some value in it, I recieve an error "Key is not present in table", but it is, I've cheked! I've even tried to write to `spnvalues` directly from `datalines`, but recieve the same error.

What's the problem?

**UPD**

I create hypertable from `DataLines`.

```
SELECT create_hypertable('datalines', 'timestamp');
```

Comment: Which Postgresql version? It works in version 9.5 to 14. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=57574fba9a69c683876a076bc95f2faf

Comment: A timestamp has a precision up to microseconds. It's highly likely that the value that you try to insert in`spnvalues` differs _slightly_ from the value in `datalines`. In general I think adding a `timestamp` value to a primary key makes sense. Especially if you already have a generated primary key (Btw: [don't use serial](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don't_Do_This#Don.27t_use_serial))

Comment: @jarlh, it's 14.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name , idk, I've tried insert through ```SELECT timestamp FROM Datalines```, but it didn't work.

Comment: [Works just fine](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=39f179550bc6b84eab0534971e6082dd) - but the combined primary key doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Please include the insert statements necessary to reproduce your error.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name , I've made an important update in question and please, read comments beneath my answer, I've written there some things. P.S. Combined primary key makes sense in my project, but this is the minimal reproducable example, so here it makes no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Foreign key constraints referencing a hypertable are not supported.](https://docs.timescale.com/timescaledb/latest/overview/limitations/#hypertable-limitations)

I've tried unique constraints, but it didn't worked out also.

So, the only way I fount to solve this problem is delete foregein key in SpnValues

```
CREATE TABLE SpnValues(
    id         BIGSERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    valueInt   BIGINT    NOT NULL            ,
    dataLineId BIGSERIAL NOT NULL            ,
    timestamp  TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
);
```

**old version**

`datalineid` must be also `NOT NULL`, the same as `timestamp`.

```
CREATE TABLE SpnValues(
    id         BIGSERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY                              ,
    valueInt   BIGINT    NOT NULL                                          ,
    dataLineId BIGSERIAL NOT NULL                                          ,
    timestamp  TIMESTAMP NOT NULL                                          ,

    FOREIGN KEY (datalineid, timestamp) REFERENCES DataLines(id, timestamp)
);
```

Comment: Doesn't matter.

Comment: @jarlh, nope, it does matter, cause I've fixed this problem only when I had made datalineid not null.

Comment: Post hoc ergo propter hoc maybe.

Comment: @Stefanov.sm , I can't help, but admit, that u r right, but I've didn't change insert requests, so if I'll find mistake I had made, I'll write here.

Comment: @Stefanov.sm , aha! I've found the problem. There's no difference is ```dataLineId``` ```NULL``` or ```NOT NULL```  until ```DataLines``` is not hypertable. When it is -- there is a difference.

Answer (score 0):

The reason may be that the `TimeStamp` value that you supply lacks precision. Internally timestamps are precise to the microsecond, i.e. your value literal must look like this `'2021-12-15 14:19:20.248137'`. So run the query below to extract all `TimeStamp` digits and retry.

```sql
select id, to_char(TimeStamp, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss.us')
from datalines;
```

Sample output:

| id | to_char |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-12-15 14:19:20.248137 |
| 2 | 2021-12-14 14:19:20.248137 |

I tried

```sql
insert into SpnValues (valueInt, dataLineId, TimeStamp) 
  values (10, 2, '2021-12-14 14:19:20.248137');
```

and it works. With millisecond precision (3 digits) it fails.